# change css style in JQuery function

Tags: jquery, css

I have a JQuery function, in which I define a span element. I just want to replace the "130px" with a variable. I have a variable with the value "width:130px". I obviously don't know how to put it in there. Thank you for any ideas!

```
link.append('<span class="title" style="width:130px">' + item.title + '</span>');
```

Comment: `link.css('width', yourVar)`. [.css](https://api.jquery.com/css) can also take an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **+** to concatenate strings.

```
link.append('<span class=\"title\" style=\"width:'+ variable + '\">' + 21 + '</span>');
```

or use `link.css({"width": yoursVariable})`

*In css() use camalCase in properties names*

```
link.css({"backgroundColor": "red"})
```

Comment: Yes it's the missing "+". Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can see I concanated a `JS` variable withing the `<span></span>` tags. Have a look at the example.

Please remember to add `display: block` to your `span` element in order to see the effect of the `width`.

```js
let link = $(".link")
let myWidth = '130px'
link.append('<span class="title" style="display: block; background-color: red; width:'+myWidth+'">' + 'title' + '</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this link.css('width', '300px');